# Jesus conversation with Allah

Tags: tafseer, prophet-isa

> And when Allah will say, “O Jesus, son of Mary, didst thou say to men, ‘Take me and my mother for two gods beside Allah?’”, he will answer, “Holy art Thou. I could never say that to which I had no right. If I had said it, Thou wouldst have surely known it. Thou knowest what is in my mind, and I know not what is in Thy mind. It is only Thou Who art the Knower of hidden things.  “I said nothing to them except that which Thou didst command me — ‘Worship Allah, my Lord and your Lord.’ And I was a witness over them as long as I remained among them, but since Thou didst cause me to die, Thou hast been the Watcher over them; and Thou art Witness over all things. (Chapter 5 Verses 116-117)

Salaam,

Can someone explain to me the meaning of these verses?

Jazakallah

Comment: They seem pretty clear to me. What do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: Jesus here is absolving all knowledge of him even knowing that Christians take him as god in this passage correct?

Comment: Relevant post https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/46316/13438

Comment: That post is not relevant to this.

Comment: @DaudAhmad I don't see where Isa (AS) says he doesn't know about Christians taking him as a god.

Comment: @The Z so you think Jesus knew that his people took him as a god? Read the passage in whichever translation of the Qur'an you want. The passage is about Allah questioning Jesus about his knowledge of what is people did after Jesus left them "as long as I remained...."

Comment: Allah did not question him about his knowledge. He questioned him about whether he told them to worship him.

Comment: Jesus says 'And I was a witness over them as long as I remained among them'- so here Jesus is saying that he knows what happened and what was said about him in his lifetime, but then Allah caused him to die then he doesn't know afterwards, hence Jesus says 'Thou hast been the Watcher over them' i.e. Allah has been watching them and Jesus knows nothing of what they said regarding him being a 'god' So Jesus is saying 'I know what they said when I was there, but I do not know anymore because I am not among them anymore' why does that not make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

Through this conversation, we are given a glimpse of the true views and words of 'Isa bin Maryam [Jesus] عليه السلام who is basically affirming that he only taught people Tawheed [worship Allah (ﷻ) alone] and rejecting the concepts of Shirk that started after he was gone; he rejects that he ever told people to worship either him or his mother. [Some Christians claim this verse gets the trinity wrong, but it's not directly speaking of the trinity].

Please note that this is a grievously inaccurate translation at:

> **...since Thou didst cause me to die...**

Islam does not say that 'Isa [Jesus] عليه السلام died. All other major well known translations say the meaning is "took me up" [hence the Islamic belief that he ascended to His Lord], not that the Angel of Death came.

My suggestion is to (a) read Tafsir Ibn Kathir whenever you need explanation of any verses and (b) be careful which translations you read from. Wa Alaikum As Salam Wr Wb

Comment: Salaam brother thanks for your response but the word that is used in arabic in this verse is "tawaffa" which means death, or to die. The Quran attests to this. It does not mean to raise up. Every time the word 'Tawaffa' is used in the Quran which is over 20 times, the word 'tawaffa' is used to mention death or to die. No where does it say "to raise". For example in 2:234 and 3:193. If you want more references I can provide. Jzk

Comment: It is not always used in the context of death. In verse 6:60, the same verb is used referring to Allah taking our souls at night (yatawaffakum bi al-layli).. it doesn't mean us literally dying every night. The verb can be used in different ways and in this context it does not mean "caused to die" because such a view would contradict the abundance of other texts that make it clear that 'Isa did not die yet.

Comment: @DaudAhmad توفي means to receive in full, it does **not** mean death, although it can be implied  to "take (in death)" as in the verses you have cited, or to take alive with body as in the case of Jesus being raised up. Consider  حتى يتوفاهن الموت ([4:15](https://quran.com/4/15)) ...  If توفا *means* death (موت) then why does it say death two times?

Comment: In the famous Arabic dictionary named Qamus it is stated:
الوَفَاةُ الموت و تَوَفَّاهُ اللهُ قبض روحه
“Al wafatu means death and Tawaffahullahu means to subdue the soul, i.e. death.
In another famous Arabic dictionary called Tajul Urus, it is written:
نفسه قبض اذا وجلّ عزّ اللهُ هُ فّاتَوَ
“Tawaffahullahu Azzawajjal means “when Allah subdues the soul, meaning causes death”
Hazrat Ibn Abbasra states:
عن ابن عباس قوله : ” إني متوفيك ” يقول : إني مميتك
“Mutawaffaka means we caused you to die.’”( Sahih Bukhari, Kitabut-Tafsir, Surah Al-Ma’idah, Under the verse Falamma tawaffaitani..)”

Comment: @DaudAhmad You should check complete definitions in [Qamus al-Muhit](https://ia800504.us.archive.org/8/items/waq10601/04_10604.pdf#page=638) , [Taj al-Urus](https://archive.org/stream/FP62880/taga40#page/n219/mode/2up) or [Arabic-English Lexicon](https://archive.org/details/anarabicenglish02lanegoog/page/n293/mode/1up). It originally means to receive in full, it can be used as an expression to imply taking of soul at death but that is not its only usage as you are implying.

Comment: As for the tafsir you have quoted, it is not found in Bukhari, and even if it is accepted, then Ibn Abbas explained it very differently, to mean death in the end of times (see [here](https://archive.org/stream/mt11_1/mt5_1#page/n237/mode/2up)).

Comment: Verses: 2:234, 3:193, 4:16, 4:97, 6:60, 6:61, 7:37, 7:127, 8:50,  10:105, 13:40, 10:46, 12:101, 16:32, 16:70, 22:5, 32:11, 40:67, 40:77, 47:27. All these verses say death or to die.

Comment: In Lanes Lexicon, One of the most famous Arabic Dictionaries it is written:

Waw-Fa-Ya = to reach the end, keep ones promise, fulfil ones engagement, pay a debt, perform a promise. tawaffa – to die. wafaat – death.

Comment: In another famous Arabic dictionary called Tajul Urus, it is written:
نفسه قبض اذا وجلّ عزّ اللهُ هُ فّاتَوَ

“Tawaffahullahu Azzawajjal means “when Allah subdues the soul, meaning causes death”

Hazrat Ibn Abbasra states:

عن ابن عباس قوله : ” إني متوفيك ” يقول : إني مميتك

“Mutawaffaka means we caused you to die.’”( Sahih Bukhari, Kitabut-Tafsir, Surah Al-Ma’idah, Under the verse Falamma tawaffaitani..)”

Comment: Also, a simple Google "meaning of tawaffa" and the first thing you will see is 'means causing to die'.

Answer (score 0):

No Jesus is not confirming his death at all this conversation would take place during judgement day and it’s to clarify to those that believe Jesus is God that Jesus never told them to worship him because in the day of judgement people will say Jesus told them that he is God Jesus is accepting responsibility when he was among them but when he was taken by Allah what they believed after him he’s not responsible for! Please don’t spread false information about Islam it’s wrong if you don’t know seek guidance don’t give your own interpretation

Answer (score -1):

This is conversation between Allah Almighty and Hadhrat Issa(jesus) AS. Confirming him and his mother were human. Most interesting thing is this jesus is confirming his death. He says I was witness when I was there but when you cause me to die You was witness. And this conversation will happen on the day of judgment. Its mean Jesus will never come back to this earth, because he knew nothing about the belief of his ummah.
[www.alislam.org](http://www.alislam.org)

Comment: Yes it is. You are right Ahsan sahab