# How do Sunni Muslims refute the Ahmadi argument on the death of Jesus (as) because of the need to eat food?

Tags: sunni, death, prophet-isa

I am an Ahmadi Muslim and I have a hard time understanding why Sunni Muslims believe Jesus (as) to be alive when in my research I have found that Quran and Ahadith make it clear that he is dead. I find the proofs presented by the Mirza Ghulam Ahmad (as) to be very powerful and I cannot refute them to the best of my ability.

One of 23 Arguments I found is the following:

> "The Messiah, son of Mary, was only a Messenger; surely, Messengers like unto him had indeed passed away before him. And his mother was a truthful woman. **They both used to eat food.** See how We explain the Signs for their good, and see how they are turned away." (5:75).

And one cannot say that Jesus (as) does not require food. Because the Quran clearly says that every prophet does:

> "And We did not give them bodies that ate no food, nor were they to live for ever." (21:8)

> "And We never sent any Messengers before thee but surely they ate food and walked in the streets. And We make some of you a trial for others. Will you then be steadfast? And thy Lord is All-Seeing." (25:20)

Jesus is not special, and he must be eating food. So, while he awaits his descent in the heavens, he must be eating food. So there is a kitchen for him in the heavens that he eats from. And there is a bathroom that he goes to relieve himself. But last time I heard there are no bathrooms or kitchens in heaven.

I would like to know how do Sunni Muslims counter this argument?

Comment: These claims only show that although being a student of Waly Allah ad-Dahlawy Mirza Ghulam is rather a Scharlatan than a scholar as his claims are only an interpretation of part of the verse not taking it as a whole. It is easier to convince and manipulate if your surroundings is ignorant of the Arabic meaning of the revelation and cherry picking the suitable information. Some answers are already provided in [Did Isa go to the cross?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46316/did-prophet-isa-go-to-the-cross)

Comment: Muslims believe in the return of Jesus because of the proof in the Quran and Sunnah. If you want refutations then you should research as there are books and organisations which deal with the cause of Khatm al-Nabuwah and refuting the Ahmadis. If you want to ask us on Islam.SE about something which you can't already find then you need to focus your question to one verse\hadith at a time, choose your strongest one and ask about that. No one is going to sit and write an answer to refute 10 pages of fallacies.

Comment: I have edited your question to focus on one point.

Comment: Please keep the question focused to one point. If you keep editing it to cover more than one then it should be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

The verses say that the Messengers ate food. However the verses do **not** say that all the Messengers need to consume food regularly throughout their lives in all circumstances. It is possible that Jesus does not require food during his stay in heavens. As evidence for this lets take the example of the Ashab Al-Kahf: They slept continuously for 309 years in a cave ([Quran 18:25](https://quran.com/18/25?translations=20)). They did not not eat during this period, only after waking up did they send a person to buy food ([Quran 18:17-19](https://quran.com/18/17-19?translations=20)). If they can live for so many years without needing food then Jesus عليه السلام  can also live for many years without needing food. Allah is able to do all things.

It is also possible that Jesus عليه السلام  does need food and is given food by Allah, such as from paradise. Adam and Eve  عليه السلام  stayed in paradise in heavens before their descent to earth. They were alive. They ate food ([Quran 2:35](https://quran.com/2/35?translations=20)). We also have another example: The table of food that came from the sky for the disciples of Jesus ([Quran 5:114-115](https://quran.com/5/114-115?translations=20)). So it is also possible for food to be available in heavens and for Jesus عليه السلام  to be provided food if he needs it. Again Allah is able to do all things.

Hence there is nothing in these two verses which negates the life of Jesus عليه السلام .

Comment: I took your edits and made my question as it should be.

Comment: If the Quran lays down principals we shouldn't give exceptions. The story of Ashab AL Kahf when taken literally violates this verse. So, to fix this contradiction we interpret the story metaphorically so it fits Quranic principals and common sense.

Comment: And Adam and Eve couldn't have been in literal heaven, since that would violate this verse:

Comment: "Fatigue shall not touch them there, nor shall they ever be ejected therefrom." (15:48). So this too must be interpreted metaphorically since if Adam and Eve were rejected from literally heaven than this verse would be falsified. In this manner the matter of Jesus (as) should be interpreted in a sense which doesn't violate these Quranic principles about prophets and their human nature. And that's only when we accept Jesus(as) to be dead.

Comment: And the verse literally says that prophets' bodies require food in 21:8. The human requirement for food is obvious and requires no explanation. So the verse states that all prophets have this requirement because they are normal humans and don't have superhuman powers. Ascribing superhuman powers to Jesus, Ashab ul Kahf, and others violates this principle.

Comment: @MunassarAlam And I am not here to debate with you, rather you asked for the orthodox response and I have provided it to you. I provided you with verses which contradict your stance, you rejected them as metaphorical ... that is the end of the discussion from my side. Any excuses you make can be applied retrorespectively from my side. e.g. If the Quran says that event X happened then we shouldn't deny it by calling it metaphorical. A specific and a general verse do not violate each other, rather they are combined.

Comment: If your aim here is to debate or proselytize rather than to learn then you are in the wrong place.

Comment: I accept that and I will hence refrain from debating here. But please keep the other verse I have as that is part of the argument. Since it says "they used to eat food."

Comment: Any other issues in other verses should be asked separately in a new question.

Comment: done! Thank you for the advice