# Do the believers in Jannah pay the Zakat?

Tags: jannah, zakat

If the believers in Jannah do pay the Zakat, how does the payment reach the recipients and in what form?

This question comes from the common Islamic belief that the life of Issa was never ended by the Jews.

In Surah 19:29-31 the Quran shows us that Issa declared

> Then she pointed to him. They said: How can we talk to one who is in the cradle, a young boy ? He spake: Lo! I am the slave of Allah. He hath given me the Scripture and hath appointed me a Prophet, And hath made me blessed wheresoever I may be, **and hath enjoined upon me prayer and almsgiving so long as I remain alive**,

So if Issa (or any other believer) is alive in Jannah, is he paying the Zakat?

Comment: Who would people in jannah pay Zakah to?

Comment: What is your basis that people dwelling in Jannah pay Zakah? Please provide the verses that say so.

Comment: Maybe you're confusing Islamic afterlife with christian afterlife. In Islam, there is a day of judgement when the world is destroyed. Then, everyone enters heaven and hell. So, no one in Jannah can pay Zakah to anyone in this world because they never happen at the same time.

Comment: So, your question is only about Isa (AS)?  Please change it to just Isa (AS) then.

Comment: Yes, Issa was the one in mind, but I'm not sure if his case is unique

Comment: It is unique. And keep in mind that there is no evidence to say that Isa (AS) is in heaven. In fact there is much evidence to the contrary.

Comment: He was just raised up. That could mean he is just in one of the skies, not necessarily in heaven. Which would mean he doesn't really have any possessions to give Zakat on.

Comment: This question is based on a rather discussed assumption: That 'Isa actually is alive or didn't die. This assumption has no consensus among scholars. See for example [Surat Al `Imran 3/55 about the death of Jesus(puh)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/22977/surat-al-imran-3-55-about-the-death-of-jesuspuh/26318#26318)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Zakat Items**

First of all zakat is only paid for certain kinds of wealth like:

Money, financial income, silver and gold (also read islamqa #[2795](https://islamqa.info/en/2795)):

> And those within whose wealth is a known right ([70:24](http://legacy.quran.com/70/24))

on fruits and grains (for details see islamqa #[99843](https://islamqa.info/en/99843)):

> And He it is who causes gardens to grow, [both] trellised and untrellised, and palm trees and crops of different [kinds of] food and olives and pomegranates, similar and dissimilar. Eat of [each of] its fruit when it yields and give its due [zakah] on the day of its harvest. And be not excessive. Indeed, He does not like those who commit excess. ([6:141](http://legacy.quran.com/6/141))

on cattle (for details see islamqa #[71267](https://islamqa.info/en/71267)):

> 'By Allah, except Whom none has the right to be worshipped) whoever had camels or cows or sheep and did not pay their Zakat, those animals will be brought on the Day of Resurrection far bigger and fatter than before and they will tread him under their hooves, and will butt him with their horns, and (those animals will come in circle): When the last does its turn, the first will start again, and this punishment will go on till Allah has finished the judgments amongst the people." ([sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1460))

I hope I didn't miss anything.

Note that we don't exactly know what of these kinds will be in Jannah, but we know that we will be given them and this without any due (tribute). So Zakat is excluded  for those (believers) who have been doing good in this life and entered Jannah as is clearly mentioned in the Qur'an:

> Whoever does an evil deed will not be recompensed except by the like thereof; but whoever does righteousness, whether male or female, while he is a believer - those will enter Paradise, being given provision therein without account. ([40:40](http://legacy.quran.com/24/38))

**'Isa and zakat**

This will apply to any of them no matter if it is 'Isa () or anybody else.

Note that you assume that 'Isa is alive this actually is a discussed matter some scholars say that he died (not by the hands of the Jews or his pursuers) and was raised to Allah, whether he is in Jannah or not is not mentioned in the Qur'an, nor is indicated in the qur'an whether he is actually alive or not. Some ahadith indicate that when he will be resurrected he won't die a second time.
Read for exampple on [Surat Al `Imran 3/55 about the death of Jesus(puh)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/22977/surat-al-imran-3-55-about-the-death-of-jesuspuh)?

So based on the above your Qur'an-quote:

> ...so long as I remain alive,

applies for 'Isa's lifetime where he is/was/will (be) able to spent or pay zakat, which is in this life only. This is the interpretation of zakat as a kind of financial tribute.

But in Arabic [zakat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakat#Etymology) also may mean a (inner) purification (for example by leaving sins and doing good deeds) that's also how the (financial) zakat was presented in the Qur'an (as a purification):

> Take, [O, Muhammad], **from their wealth a charity by which you purify them and cause them increase**, and invoke [ Allah 's blessings] upon them. Indeed, your invocations are reassurance for them. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing. ([9:103](http://legacy.quran.com/9/103))

Comment: According to this hadith: https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/394, it seems Prophet (SAW) will be the first person the gates of paradise will be open to. So, the premise that Isa (AS) is in paradise may be flawed

Answer (score 3):

Zakat is due on material wealth when it is above nisab and a full year passes on it.

Did Isa own material wealth (مال) in excess of nisab, when he was raised up?

If the answer is **no**, then the obligation is lifted from him till he comes to own it.

If the answer is **yes**, then in whose custody is that wealth currently? The obligation of paying Zakat on that wealth is shifted to that guardian (ولي) who will pay it from the same wealth until the Zakat depletes it below Nisab.